# Let $G$ be a group, $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $h$ be a fixed element of $G$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $h$ be a fixed element of $G$. Show that the subset $gHg^{-1}=\{ghg^{-1}:h\in H\} $ is a subgroup of $G$.

I know of the one and two-step tests for subgroups but I'm at a loss on how to implement either of them as I'm not sure what the inverse is.

Comment: The inverse of $abc$  is $c^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}$ :)

Answer (score 1):

For the inverse,
$$
(ghg^{-1})(gh^{-1}g^{-1})=gh(g^{-1}g)h^{-1}g^{-1}=ghh^{-1}g^{-1}=e.
$$
The choice $h=e$ yields $e\in gHg^{-1}$, and multiplication is straightforward as above by cancelling the $gg^{-1}$ term.

Answer (score 1):

These are the three tests that need to be done, and how to do them in *this specific* case.

1. Is $e$ contained in $gHg^{-1}$? Yes, since $e = geg^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$.
2. Is $gHg^{-1}$ multiplicatively closed? Yes, since if $gag^{-1}, gbg^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}$, then we have $(gag^{-1})(gbg^{-1}) = ga(g^{-1}g)bg^{-1}= g(ab)g^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$.
3. Is, for any element $gag^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$, the inverse $(gag^{-1})^{-1}$ contained in $gHg^{-1}$? Yes, since for any product $kl$ in any group, $(kl)^{-1} = l^{-1}k^{-1}$ (this can easily be extended to three elements), we have
   $$
   (gag^{-1})^{-1} = (g^{-1})^{-1}a^{-1}g^{-1} = ga^{-1}g^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}
   $$